# How to give href to navigation bars buttons like ion-item

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I want to add href to navigation bar buttons like we do for the ion-item. 
For example:

```
<ion-list>

    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
    Dashboard
    </ion-item>        
    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/aboutus">
    About Us
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

I want exactly this to happen for navigation buttons. But I couldn't find a href thing for button. 
I tried both `$state.go('app.home')` and `$window.location.href = '#/app/home';` for the button and both works. But it hides the menu button in the navigation bar with a back button. I do not want it to be happen like that. I want the menu button there. Like when we click the 'dashboard' in the menu.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want a back button then disable/remove it from the view. Place the buttons you want in its place. Ionic has some pretty simple documentation on bar buttons like this [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sam. @Sam5487. But instead for remove the button, iam looking for a solution which behave like the ion-item's href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.

In the ion-side-menus tag, write enable-menu-with-back-views attribute value to 'true', which is 'false' by default.

Eg:
enable-menu-with-back-views="true"

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can not use "href" tag for `<ion-item>`. `<ion-item>` tag is only used under `<ion-list>`

It seems you are trying to make tabs. If it is correct you can create tab view project of ionic using following command.
"ionic start myApp tabs"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not trying to create a tab. It's a sidemenu app